# how to pass data intent in different textview in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I have 3 activities layouts. In the first layout I want the user to input a number that had displayed (almost same with captcha) and in the second layout too. Next i want to pass the result to the last layout.

Here is my code.

firstlayout:

```
EditText periksaAnsTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et);
    int periksaAns = Integer.valueOf(periksaAnsTxt.getText().toString());
    Intent hasilIntent = new Intent(this, Soal2.class);
    int hasilBNormal;
    int hasilBTotal;

    if (periksaAns == 12){
        hasilBNormal = 1;
        hasilIntent.putExtra("hasilBNormal1",hasilBNormal);
    }else {
        hasilBTotal = 1;
        hasilIntent.putExtra("hasilBTotal1", hasilBTotal);
    }
    startActivity(hasilIntent);
```

the second:

```
EditText periksaAnsTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et);

    int periksaAns = Integer.valueOf(periksaAnsTxt.getText().toString());
    Intent hasilIntent = new Intent(this, HasilActivity.class);

    int hasilBNormal;
    int hasilBMerahHijau;
    int hasilBTotal;


    if (periksaAns == 8){
        hasilBNormal = 1;
        hasilIntent.putExtra("hasilBNormal2",hasilBNormal);


    }else if (periksaAns == 3){
        hasilBMerahHijau = 1;
        hasilIntent.putExtra("hasilBMerahHijau1", hasilBMerahHijau);

    }else {
        hasilBTotal = 1;
        hasilIntent.putExtra("hasilTotal2", hasilBTotal);
    }
    startActivity(hasilIntent);
```

and the layout which shows the result is :

```
Intent hasilIntent = getIntent();
  Integer hasilNormal1 = hasilIntent.getIntExtra("hasilBNormal1",1);
  Integer hasilNormal2 = hasilIntent.getIntExtra("hasilBNormal2",1);
  Integer hasilTotal1 = hasilIntent.getIntExtra("hasilBTotal1",1);
  Integer hasilTotal2 = hasilIntent.getIntExtra("hasilBTotal2",1);
  Integer hasilMerahHijau = hasilIntent.getIntExtra("hasilBMerahHijau1",1);

  TextView hasilNormalView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtNormal);
  TextView hasilMerahHijauView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtMerahHijau);
  TextView hasilTotalView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtTotal);

  float bNormal = (hasilNormal1 + hasilNormal2)/2 *100;
  String bNormalStr = String.valueOf(bNormal);
  float bMerahHijau = hasilMerahHijau*100;
  String bMerahHijauStr = String.valueOf(bMerahHijau);

  float bTotal = (hasilTotal1 + hasilTotal2)/2*100;
  String bTotalStr = String.valueOf(bTotal);

  hasilNormalView.setText("Normal : " + bNormalStr + '%');
  hasilMerahHijauView.setText("Buta Warna Merah + Hijau : " + bMerahHijauStr + '%');
  hasilTotalView.setText("Buta Warna Total : " + bTotalStr + '%');
```

so if they input number 12 in layout1 or 8 in layout 2, then hasilBnormal is increase and other will not increase (do nothing), but i hv problem here. if hasilBNormal increase so do others, please help me to fix this.

here is the xml in third layout:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:id="@+id/txtNormal"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="110dp" />


<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:id="@+id/txtMerahHijau"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtNormal"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:id="@+id/txtTotal"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtMerahHijau"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

Comment: u are using default value as 1 for all variables. if there is no value then 1 is stored in those variables.

Comment: so how could i increase point if the user put the correct answers? for example if they answer 12 in layout 1, the point of hasilBnormal is up to one point, but others will not. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand fully what's the purpose of your code, or the semantics of the variables, but I believe you want to set the default value to 0 on your `getIntExtras`

```
Integer hasilNormal1 = hasilIntent.getIntExtra("hasilBNormal1", 0); 
Integer hasilNormal2 = hasilIntent.getIntExtra("hasilBNormal2", 0);
...
```

Also, it seems that you are losing the contents of the first Intent on the second Activity.

In your second Activity you should copy the contents of the first Intent to the second Intent:

```
hasilIntent.putExtra("hasilBNormal1", getIntent().getIntExtra("hasilBNormal1", 0));
hasilIntent.putExtra("hasilBTotal1", getIntent().getIntExtra("hasilBTotal1", 0));
```